# not able to access application.yml file credentials in rails 7 using figaro gem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-7, rails7

I am using ruby 3.1.0 and rails 7.0.4, I have configured Figaro gem, but not able to access its keys in the rails console.

this is the application.yml content.

app/config/application.yml

```
 production:
   stripe_api_key: sk_live_EeHnL644i6zo4Iyq4v1KdV9H
   stripe_publishable_key: pk_live_9lcthxpSIHbGwmdO941O1XVU
```

I need the value of the key in the rails console.

thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the above answer, first, we need to start the rails console in production mode using the below command.

```
rails c or console -e production
```

then we can easily access the keys in the rails console.

```
ENV["stripe_api_key"]

=> "sk_live_EeHnL644i6zo4Iyq4v1KdV9H"

ENV["stripe_publishable_key"]

=> "pk_live_9lcthxpSIHbGwmdO941O1XVU"
```

this worked for me.

thanks!